# jqgrid custom client side search with loadonce true?

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I have a problem with building a searching block related to my jqgrid.

I want this search is client-side based and I use loadonce: true to get data from my asmx service.

Then How to use the criteria to do the complex search.(outside the grid, I mean do not use the default search block provided by jqGrid, Cause I may implement the search block in other page)